# variable not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm making a program for class, and for some reason it is giving me this error when it is declared in the class definition.

> error: in function `'void setMessageBuffer(std::string)'`
>   error: `'message'` was not declared in this scope.

```
class apple
{
     private:
         string message, message2;

     public:
         void setMessageBuffer(string);
};

void apple::setMessageBuffer(string messagebuff)
{
     message = messagebuff;
}
```

I've done other parts of the program like that and they work fine, but for some reason this part doesn't seem to want to compile.

Comment: Error message and code sample contradict each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put `apple::` in front of the method name.  Your error message tells me this!

```
error: in function 'void setMessageBuffer(std::string)'
error: 'message' was not declared in this scope.
```

Contrast that with:

```
template.cpp: In member function ‘void apple::setMessageBuffer(std::string)’:
template.cpp:14:7: error: ‘another variable’ was not declared in this scope
```

(Apologies if I'm wrong here, maybe it's just how my compiler is behaving, g++-4.6)

Comment: that was the problem. i had forgotten the class part of that. thanks. classes are so much easier to make in java....

Comment: Note that apple::message is declared private, so that should you attempt to use it in a non-member function, that would be a scope error and also fail.  Had you intended to use a non-member function to access a private member, that would have been a different issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is something wrong in other parts of your code, for example, did you include `string` ? and `using namespace std;`?

The following  code can be compiled by GCC without any problem

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class apple
{
    private:
        string message, message2;

    public:
        void setMessageBuffer(string);
};

void apple::setMessageBuffer(string messagebuff)
{
    message = messagebuff;
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: ya, i have that at the top of the program. it works with another function have for the class (the other function takes in another class object and sets the class object created in this class to the one given at the beginning)  <-- if that makes since. i tried it in another part of the program that is similar, and added the same thing, and it works for that part, just not for this class for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The error message and the code don't agree: the code compiled to produce the error message lacked `apple::` in front of `setMessageBuffer()`: without the function being a member function, it can't access `apple`'s members. The code as posted compiles assuming it is preceded by the two lines

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

(or, in my opinion preferable, without the second of these two lines and all uses of `string` being prefixed by `std::`).